# How to open transparent activity from UnityPlayerActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, transparency, unity-game-engine

I'm writing Android plugin for Unity3D. I need to open my custom activity from UnityPlayerActivity so it is transparent and game is visible in background. But when I open my activity, the UnityPlayerActivity becomes black, so I have a black background instead of transparent. I need a help how to use this transparency feature with Unity3D.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.activities.MyActivity" 
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, my theory is that the underlying unity activity calls onPause, which causes it to stop its own update, thus it renders an empty page.. maybe someone else can confirm as well? I still don't have a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

One convenient way of making an Activity transparent is specifying

```
<activity
  ...
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, in combination with a transparent background color for the root `ViewGroup` of your activity layout.

If you already tried this (or a similar approach to Activity transparency), please post a description of what you tried, including your exact code and relevant bits of XML, into your question. It will help everyone provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Already tried android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". I'm sure that my Activity is transparent because when I call it from usual Android activity it is transparent, but when I call it from UnityPlayer Activity- background becomes black. So the problem is with Unity3d.

    <activity android:name="com.example.activities.MyActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

Comment: same problem here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unity Engine purposefully adds `Window` dim amount, So we need to make it transparent after the **onCreate** of activity.

For example,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setDimAmount(0); //Making the window dim transparent
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
}
```